# How can I automatically calculate values of multiple radio buttons checked in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I am practicing on some web app using jsp. I have six groups of three radio buttons. My question is this: is there a way, and how it can be done, to when a button is checked to automatically get its value and to calculate it with given parameters? Do I have to write code for each possible option, or is there an easier way? Thank you very much.
Here is my java in jsp code:

```
int start = 1500;
        double good = 1.3; 
        double bad = 0.6;
        double poor = 0.3;
         String result = null;
       result= request.getParameter("kvadrat");



        if(request.getParameter("access")!=null && request.getParameter("location")!=null &&                
request.getParameter("gabariti")!=null
                && request.getParameter("height")!=null && request.getParameter("infra")!=null && 
request.getParameter("terrain")!=null)

        {
            if( request.getParameter("access").equals("good") && 
request.getParameter("lcation").equals("good")
                    && request.getParameter("gabariti").equals("good")&& 
request.getParameter("vrsta").equals("good")
                    && request.getParameter("infra").equals("good")&& 
request.getParameter("terrain").equals("good"))
            {
                out.println("Your price is: " + Double.parseDouble(result)*start*good);
```

Comment: how about using `ajax` and `jquery` ?

Comment: I'll try that, thank you.